# I can't create a Stripe customer and subscribe him to a plan in Android

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, networkonmainthread

I'm using Stripe and I get the card token but I can't create a customer. Android Studio gives me a NetworkOnMainThreadException with the Internet permission on the manifest. This is my code:

```
public void registerOnClick(View v)
    {
        Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", 12, 2017, "123");
        boolean validation = card.validateCard();
        Debug.log("Is it validate? "+validation);
        if (validation)
        {
            new Stripe().createToken(
                    card,
                    PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                    new TokenCallback()
                    {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token)
                        {
                            Debug.log("TOKEN: "+token);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toke achieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            RequestOptions requestOptions = (new RequestOptions.RequestOptionsBuilder()).setApiKey(SECRET_KEY).build();
                            Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            customerParams.put("source", token.getId()); // Token ID
                            customerParams.put("plan", "mumsclub"); //The plan created in Stripe dashboard
                            customerParams.put("email", "tabo@example.com");
                            try {
                                Customer.create(customerParams, requestOptions);
                            } catch (StripeException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        public void onError(Exception error)
                        {
                            Debug.log("Token not retrieved");
                        }
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.log("Card is not valid");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do any of this in your Android application as those calls require your Secret API key. You should never have the Secret API key in your Android application otherwise an attacker could get his hands on it and then create charges, refunds or transfers on your behalf.

What you need to do here is create a card token first and then send it to your server where you will create the charge or the customer using your Secret key. Nothing of this can happen in your Android application.

Comment: Thank you so much, it has sense